# Javascript_ Error in user.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, articulate-storyline

Here is some problems with it. 
I would like to ask you how to cope with this problem? Actually I'm new to Javascript.
Thank you in advance.

It looks like this on the console:

> Javascript_ Error in user.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
function checkPassword(form) {
  var password = checkPassword(password);
  var s_letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"; 
  var b_letters = "QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM"; 
  var digits = "0123456789"; 
  var specials = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=\|/.,:;[]{}"; 
  var is_s = false; 
  var is_b = false;
  var is_d = false; 
  var is_sp = false; 

  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    if (!is_s && s_letters.indexOf(password[i]) != -1) is_s = true;
    else if (!is_b && b_letters.indexOf(password[i]) != -1) is_b = true;
    else if (!is_d && digits.indexOf(password[i]) != -1) is_d = true;
    else if (!is_sp && specials.indexOf(password[i]) != -1) is_sp = true;
  }

  var rating = 0;
  var text = "";
  if (is_s) rating++; 
  if (is_b) rating++; // 
  if (is_d) rating++; // 
  if (is_sp) rating++; // 
  if (password.length < 6 && rating < 3) text = "Bad";
  else if (password.length < 6 && rating >= 3) text = "Good";
  else if (password.length >= 8 && rating < 3) text = "Good";
  else if (password.length >= 8 && rating >= 3) text = "Excellent";
  else if (password.length >= 6 && rating == 1) text = "Bad";
  else if (password.length >= 6 && rating > 1 && rating < 4) text = "Good";
  else if (password.length >= 6 && rating == 4) text = "Excellent";
  console.log(text); // Alert will not work for us here. Console.log allows you to export data to the console for troubleshooting.
  return text;
}

var player = GetPlayer(); // Gets the player object.
var myPassword = player.GetVar("SystemDate"); // Gets the value for myPassword
console.log(myPassword);
var newValue = checkPassword(myPassword); // Run the function and return to newValue
player.SetVar("SystemDate",newValue); // Set the value of newValue back to Storyline
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? You get this error when you try to access the `value` property on a `undefined` object. For eg: If you have `element.value`, element should be `undefined`

Comment: You're asking javascript to use a value from some variable that it either hasn't created or can't access (for example, if you've got a function and you're trying to access a variable internal to ANOTHER function, they can't see each other!)

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Here: var newValue = checkPassword(myPassword); you are calling the checkPassword() with the password from whit I understand from your comments. So, the problem is in this line: var password = form.password.value; try changing the function header to checkPassword(password) and remove that first line from your function.

Comment: As I see you are new here: it really helps your point to use the "code" button in the editor when pasting code - when used properly, you should get some indentation in the lines where your code is. Also, there is a nifty preview box on the bottom so you can see how your question will look like.

Comment: you don't have element (input) with `name="password"` in your `form` parameter. Add `console.log(myPassword);` after `var myPassword = ...` and report the browser console output.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I'm new here, many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply

Comment: I have changed it. Here is another error

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @MarinaSkorohod Марина, put line `function checkPassword(form) {` back in your code and move line `console.log(myPassword);` after line `var myPassword = player.GetVar("SystemDate");` and before line `var newValue = checkPassword(myPassword);`.

Comment: Thank you, Igor, I have changed it. And now there is another mistake...Error in user.js 5qBiWS7wNUT RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @MarinaSkorohod please, return the code to the way it was two changes ago (your are now calling `checkPassword` from `checkPassword` indefinitely - hence, stack size error). The only thing that I was asking to add was line `console.log(myPassword);` between `var myPassword = player.GetVar("SystemDate");` and `var newValue = checkPassword(myPassword);`.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your function in a little, try that one (and show us `SetValue` function):

```
// @first error - password input, not the form
function checkPassword (password) {
    var expr, 
        rating = 0, 
        rules = {
            // Lower case
            '/[a-z]+/g': false,
            // Upper case
            '/[A-Z]+/g': false,
            // Numbers
            '/[0-9]+/g': false,
            // Special symbols
            '/[^\w\s]/gi': false
        };

    for (expr in rules) {
        if (password.match(expr)) {
            // rules[expr] = true; // - can be used to show the proper message of invalidation
            rating++;
        }
    }

    return 
        || password.length >= 8 && rating >= 3 && "Excellent"
        || password.length < 6 && rating >= 3 && "Good"
        || password.length >= 8 && rating < 3 && "Good"
        || password.length >= 6 && rating > 1 && rating < 4 && "Good"
        || "Bad";
}

// Gets the player object.
var player = GetPlayer(); 
// Gets the value for myPassword
var myPassword = player.GetVar("SystemDate"); 
// Run the function and return to newValue
var newValue = checkPassword(myPassword); 
// Set the value of newValue back to Storyline
// @second error seems to be in the function SetVar
player.SetVar("SystemDate",newValue);
```